# Macros in the Cider repl (e.g. ->)

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

why is the use of the threading macro ->> producing an error in the cider-repl:

```
(-> "x..")

//  Unable to resolve symbol: -> in this context
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this happens when you create a new namespace in the repl and have not yet defined *anything* in it. so the aliases for the clojure.core functions have not yet been established:

start by creating a new blank namespace:

```
user> (in-ns 'i-dont-exist-yet)
#namespace[i-dont-exist-yet]
```

Then try to use the threading macro (or anything from clojure.core):

```
i-dont-exist-yet> (-> 1)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: -> in this context, compiling:(*cider-repl api*:47:18)
```

which fails to lookup the symbol `->` in the current namespace, though it works if you tell it which namespace to use explicitly:

```
i-dont-exist-yet> (clojure.core/-> 1)
1
```

There is a convenience function in clojure.core that will add all the expected refers for your new namespce. You won't need to do this when you create your namespace from a file with the `ns` macro at the top because `ns` does this for you (amongst other useful things):

```
i-dont-exist-yet> (clojure.core/refer-clojure)
nil
i-dont-exist-yet> (-> 1)
1
```

Comment: cool, thank you. I figured out that just changing to the namespace in the cider repl (via in-ns..) is not sufficient. C-c M-n does the job however.